Weight Vocabulary - sort vocabulary - (not terms)
I need to sort the vocabularies in a page based on admin choice. To be clear, I am not talking about terms, I am talking about the vocabulary, the parent holding the terms.
As per what I read, Vocabulary seems not fieldable unfortunately. If it is, I am not sure how. I found a few db hacks but not sure I wan to implement this if not supported.
Can anyone share any tip to add a weight field to a vocabulary?
Or maybe a custom solution/module that would allow me to register the order in which I want the vocabulary to be displayed on?

You can create a new view with list of vocabularies and sort them according to your need and display the view in place of existing vocabulary view.

Thanks. We ended up creating a View display mode in fact and sorting the vocabulary there. I was hoping for a more straight forward integration of the weight values of Vocabularies though, like a module or something. Thanks for the time spent answering me.

We ended up creating a View display mode in fact and sorting the vocabulary there. I was hoping for a more straight forward integration of the weight values of Vocabularies though, like a module or something.
